# synchronize udp broadcast file transfer

Tags: c, udp, file-transfer, broadcasting

I'm currently working on a udp socket program that broadcasts over subnet directed address (192.168.0.255). I have an image file in the server and I will send it to 3 clients. Everything works fine, but the only problem is the receiving client doesn't always finish at the same time with the server. Any tips in synchronizing udp transfer? Thank you

Comment: Why not use TFTP, which implements some synchronization on top of UDP/IP?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to implement a UDP based TFTP, I'm just eliminating latency.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I am trying to implement a UDP based TFTP

From Wikipedia, [Trivial File Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol):

> TFTP is a simple protocol for transferring files, implemented on top
>   of the UDP/IP protocols …

Since TFTP is already based on UDP, you can quit reinventing the same.

> … the current specification for the protocol can be found in RFC 1350.

Answer (score 0):

Use TFTP

> I'm just eliminating latency...

Then use use [RFC 7440 - TFTP windowsize Option](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7440)